# Remove / overwrite some functions in buddypress.js

Tags: plugins, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, buddypress

What's the best practice to overwrite some JS-functions in buddypress.js?

There are some quite annoying things in there like animating the form-fields on click/blur/post which I need to remove because they absolutely don't fit our design.

Would the best be to copy the whole script into my theme and deregister / enqueue? If so, who knows the deregister-name?

Any other possibilities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is `bp-legacy-js`.

But if you place a buddypress.js in `wp-content/themes/your-theme/buddypress/js/` this file will be taken instead. The handle will be `bp-parent-js`

The same goes for CSS files, if you place them in `/your-theme/buddypress/css/`.

If you place the buddypress.js in a childtheme, the handle will be `bp-child-js`.